# WCF service running under domain account

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one WCF service (self-hosted) running under network service account. Service client successfully use all methods hosted by the service. When I change service credentials from network service account to domain user account - service client not able to contact service (timeout expired and exception throws).

Can anyone help me properly configure service/client/domain account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the service actually started while running under your domain account? If you're not sure (I wouldn't be), try navigating to the service URL with a browser by putting the URL into the address bar and hitting enter. If the service is running, it should (if you have mex enabled) show you the WSDL page for the service.

One problem could be that your domain account does not have admin rights (isn't part of the administrators group) on the server where the web service is running. If that's the case, WCF service won't start under that user account since starting a WCF service reserves a port on teh machine, a task that only administrators can do.